# Is the actor the one physically interacting with the system, or the one making someone do it?

Tags: uml, use-case

I have a scenario where a customer calls and gets an appointment at a garage. When drawing a UML Use Case Diagram, is the actor who is connected to placing this appointment inside the system (a) the customer, or (b) the employee?

Comment: both. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case#Actors

Comment: Ahh, doesn't seem to be one correct answer for this... From UMLDistilled "The primary actor is the actor with the goal the use case is trying to satisfy and is usually, but not always, the initiator of the use case.", while other sources states that the actor is the one doing the direct interaction with the system...

Comment: In practice the correct answer is which every communicates the scenario with the most clarity & accurancy.  If the customer is an actor that interacts with the system (e.g. via Web Interface), or always via an employee.  In the latter little to be gained by including them.

Answer (score 1):

The person that has their fingers on the keyboard and mouse is the actor. The person calling in is important from a business perspective, but not as important as the customer service rep that is interacting with the system.

Knowing that the actor is a CSR helps the screen designer and even the developer, because they will work from that perspective, ask for requirements or design clarifications from that perspective, and the system will be better as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the conflict exisits is because of the point of the project when you start drawing these use cases.

In your example, you already know that there is a CSR using 'a system' to make the booking.

However the design could have started from scractch. If this had happened the initial broad use case would have been 'a customer wishes to make a booking'. This could have lead to a number of differenc cases i.e. a customer will call a telephone number and an automated service will make the booking, a customer arrives at the garage and uses a terminal to make a booking or (as in your case) talks to a CSR (however that is i.e. phone or face2face) and they make the booking.

In many examples the customer would be the main actor in the system. However in your design the CSR is the one holding the mouse/keyboard/phone/pen or whatever and you don't need to design the iteraction between the customer and the CSR! Most societies did that years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be both. It depends. There is no single good way to model this. I would personally opt for the customer.

It is btw perfectly alright to include the phone as part of your system. So the boundary of a system does not have to be a defined by screen, mouse, keyboard. A printer might be included too as part of the system. I have written use case where it was quite essential that users printed some information and file that.

Who is the important actor here? The customer right? It is interesting to note here that Alistair Cockburn extended the actor and goals model of Ivar Jacobson with the actors and 'interests' model. His advice is to also think about who cares (or gets hurt) if user goal fails.

Is it important to get the actor just right? It is useful to brainstorm actors to find all user goals against the system. When you are confident you have found all goals, the actor is not so important anymore. Would you 'write' a completely different use case depending on this decision? Would a different system be build based on the outcome of this decision?

Who initiates the interaction? What is the event initiates it? This event is the decision of customer to call to make an appointment.

You could model customer as primary and employee as secondary actor helping customer to reach user goal. Both use phone and system to reach the goal, customer helped by employee. How they do that exactly is design?

Another consideration is that the 'actor' is a role. So you could use a role Appointment Maker. Some people care a lot about keeping job titles separate from roles as there typically some flexibility in roles that job titles perform.

There are also people who are of opinion that use of 'system' in describing use case is undesirable. They feel that it is a design/implementation decision and so they prefer more neutral 'Performer'. The Performer could be a system but also a human. In use case texts they use 'Initiator' and 'Performer' and in introduction of the use case text they explain that the 'Initiator' is in use case the Appointment Maker.

I personally think it would be fine and better if the use case was described as if customer was the one operating the system. The employee is just passing along information from system to customer and vice versa.

The book by Alistair Cockburn is a recommended read. His insights really helped me with questions like this one. It also helps to make sense of UML in relation to use case